# Search Between Two Models in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, gis

I apologize in advance is this question is too broad, but I need some help conceptualizing.

The end result is that I want to enable radius-based searching. I am using Django. To do this, I have two classes: Users and Places. Inside the Users class is a function that defines the radius in which people want to search. Inside the Places class I have a function that defines the midpoint if someone enters a city and state and not a zip (i.e., if someone enters New York, NY a lot of zipcodes are associated with that so I needed to find the midpoint).

I have those two parts down. So now I have a radius where people want to search and I know (the estimate) of the places. Now, I am having a tremendous amount of difficulty combining the two, or even thinking about HOW to do this.

I attempted doing the searching against each other in the view, but I ran into a lot of trouble when I was looping through one model in the template but trying to display results based on an if statement of the other model.

It seemed like a custom template tags would be the solution for that problem, but I wanted to make sure I was conceptualizing the problem correctly in the first place. I.e.,

- Do I want to do the displays based on an if statement in the template?
- Or should I be creating another class based on the other two in my models file?
- Or should I create a new column for one of the classes in the models file?

I suppose my ultimate question is, based on what it is I want to do (enable radius based searching), where/how should most of the work be done? Again, I apologize if the question is overly broad.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could put it in the view which renders the search page.

asuuming you have a view function like `search` you could:

1. get users radius `request.user.get_radius`
2. search for places based on that radius `relevant_places = Places.get_all_places_in_radius`
3. Render those places to a user

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would I do that with a filter? I.e., Places.objects.filter(...) ... I think I'm getting hung up here because my midpoint value is a function ... Is there some documentation that I'm missing that could be help me out with that?

Comment: how are you actually getting all zipcodes inside of a radius? do you have a function yet?  If you don't geodjango would be extremely usedful, you could save zip codes and their corresponding lat/lng and then search for all zip codes in a radius using `.filter`

Comment: I have a function that gets the radius in which users want to search, and I have a function that gets the location of the place. Both are in latitude and longitude coordinates. However, they exist inside of different classes, and I'm getting hung up on how to integrate them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are describing, I believe GeoDjango would be worth your time to look into: http://geodjango.org/

Especially if you want to enable radius based searching, most of the heavy lifting is already done by GeoDjango, you'll just have to invest some time learning how to use it (which is a small fraction of the time you would have had to spend "reinventing the wheel", so to speak)

Comment: I felt that geodjango was overkill for what I wanted to do, so I went the zipcode database right. I could go to geodjango, but I the thing is, I feel like I am very close to the solution. I do have all the information that I need, I just need to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to add the function to the view so that the information can be input directly into the model after a user enters it. Thanks for the help. I'll probably wind up looking into geodjango.